# How did Cornelius Evazan and Ponda Baba escape Jedha?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

[Supposing that the characters we see on Jedha *are* Evazan and Baba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149750/were-these-characters-the-same-as-in-a-new-hope), how did they escape Jedha?

Most people in the city seemed liked they were very much *ended*. Do any of the novelizations or comics address whether or not this pair took off right away after their cameo? Official commentary?

The question linked above indicates that maybe Legends canon may be the only source, if The Story Group hasn't done anything with these two. As long as the evidence acknowledges that they were on Jedha at that time, it's valid for my purposes.

Comment: He didn't get the death sentence on twelve systems by staying in the same place.

Comment: There are possible future works at play here: *Guardians of the Whills* is a new book coming this summer that shows Baze and Chirut prior to the events of Rogue One; maybe a glancing reference there. It's possible there could be a reference as well in the Rogue One sequel book *Inferno Squad*

Comment: @NKCampbell Well, I'm not asking about future works, and so the policy doesn't really kick in unless I'm asking specifically about them. But I know there's a novelization I ain't got time to read, and a slew of comics, and director's commentary I can't listen to, all which exist now, so...

Comment: i didn't mean 'future works' in terms of downvoting or closing - sorry. Just that there is stuff on the way that may answer the question. PS - where is there a director's commentary?

Comment: Did you say... "novelization"? <blows the Valorum whistle>

Comment: @NKCampbell No worries, I just wanted to be clear because sometimes those votes happen. Anyway, I guess I'm wrong about the _commentary_, that'll be on the 3D release. But assume I said "featurettes" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There was plenty of time for them to leave before the attack.

In the behind-the-scenes interview *Rogue One Secrets Revealed*, this is actually brought up.   In the video, Pablo Hidalgo (of the Lucasfilm Story Group) says they left the same way anyone else would have—on a ship of some sort.  Remember, the Star Destroyer departed while the group was still a significant distance away from Saw Gerrera's hideout, and the city wasn't destroyed until some time after they reached their destination.   Taking that into consideration, our favorite jerks had almost certainly at least an hour, probably several, to escape during the Imperial evacuation phase.

Comment: This would be great if you could find exactly where you saw this. Like, which video and maybe a timestamp.

Comment: @CreationEdge Found it!

Answer (score 7):

According to the screenwriter for Rogue One Gary Whitta, the pair were already heading off-world when they bumped into our heroes, potentially as much as half a day before the Death Star arrived.

No specific method of travel is indicated, but given that Evazan is a man of some wealth and Baba is a wanted criminal, I think we can assume that they chartered a private transport of some description.

> **Q.** *How did "my friend doesn't like you" survive the attack on Jedha?*
>
> **Whitta:** ***They were on their way off-world. Lucky escape, not quite so lucky later in the week.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter -](https://twitter.com/GaryWhitta/status/811351220648431616) Spelling and grammar corrected</sup></sub>

Comment: "later in the week"......interesting. If this statement is taken at face value, then that helps with some of the speculation as to how soon did Vader start chasing Leia after the last scene of Rogue One.